# Subprocess call find -exec doesn't execute

Tags: python, find, subprocess, exec

I try to delete all folders including contents through a Python subprocess call using find and rm.

The folder to be deleted is `/root/subfolder/folder20200802`.

In shell terminal, root dir, the command works:

```
find . -name 'folder2*' -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

My script, saved in root dir, gives no error but it didn't delete the folder either:

```
from subprocess import call
import os

call(['find', '.', '-name', '\'folder2*\'', '-type', 'd', '-exec', 'rm', '-rf', '{}', ';'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By writing the output to a file, I was able to debug:

```
from subprocess import call
import os
call(['find', '.', '-name', 'folder2*', '-type', 'd', '-exec', 'rm', '-rf', '{}', ' ', ';'])
```